# Julia code optimization : is this the time to use SIMD?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization, julia, simd

I am struggling to optimize my Julia code and make it run faster.

I abstracted a part of my whole code and I want you to evaluate if there are some bottlenecks which make the process slower than that of optimized one.

A brief explanation of the code:

- Let `array1` n x n array ,which is initialize with random  entries with `randn`
- `array1` would be updated under a certain algorithm in the loop until all the entries of `array1` would be bigger than -0.8
- If the loop does not end within 100000 loops, the loop ends forcibly.

```
using Random;

function Test()
  
    n=5
    sqn = n^2
    foo1 = circshift(collect(1:n)', (0, 1))
    foo2 = circshift(collect(1:n)', (0, -1))
    foo3 = circshift(collect(1:n), 1)
    foo4 = circshift(collect(1:n), -1)


    # initialize array1 with random entries
    array1 = randn(n,n);
    # initialize array2 with zeros
    array2 = zeros(n,n);

    #println(array1);

    loop = 0
  
    while minimum(array1) < -0.8 && loop < 100000
                loop += 1
                bar = zeros(n, n)
    
                # Use simd?
                for i = 1:sqn
                    bar[i] = max(0, array1[i] - 0.2)
                end
    
                array2 += bar
                
                adding = zeros(n, n)
                # Use simd?
                for i = 1:n
                    for j = 1:n
                        adding[i, j] =
                            (1 / 4) * sum([
                                bar[i, foo1[j]],
                                bar[i, foo2[j]],
                                bar[foo3[i], j],
                                bar[foo4[i], j],
                            ])
                    end
                end
                array1 = array1 - bar + adding
            end
   # println(array1)
   # println(array2)
   # println(loop)

end
Test()
```

I think I can save time using `@simd` at some `for statement`.

Is there better way of writing or superior algorithm?
If you have any useful information other than `SIMD`, I would be happy to hear it.

Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: SIMD instructions can help a lot for `bar[i] = max(0, array1[i] - 0.2)`, if the compiler isn't *already* auto-vectorizing that for you.  (You'd hope so; it's relatively easy to vectorize).  And ideally also folding the `array2 += bar` work into that loop, using each vector of `bar` as it's produced.  So IDK whether a typical Julia compiler would need any help to vectorize that.  The `adding = zeros(n, n)` initialization hopefully optimizes away if the compiler sees that every element is written inside the loop.

Comment: The `sum()` part is harder: I don't know Julia but I assume that's using elements of one array to index another, in which case you'd want "gather" instructions ( AVX2 / AVX-512, or ARM SVE I think) to use the elements of a vector as separate indices into memory.  (Without that, you could vectorize the `bar[foo3[i], j]` and `bar[foo4[i], j]` parts, though, since those are both contiguous memory for contiguous `j`.)

Comment: Or even better, if foo3 and foo4 are derived from the same thing, perhaps just do that calculation on the fly instead of creating vectors of indices.  I haven't understood the point of the algorithm (because I don't know Julia so I can only guess what some of the syntax or `circshift` does), so it's not easy to see what algorithmic optimization could be done.

Comment: Thank you. I tried SIMD at for loops in the code above, but the performance didn't change. (The Julia compiler might automatically use SIMD without users explicitly instructing it) But, replacing `sum()` with just summing with `+` worked and it speeded up by 2 times.

Comment: The first thing you should do is to avoid allocations in the loop, especially in the inner loop. `sum([bar[i, foo1[j]], ...` makes a 4-element array every time, it should just be `bar[i, foo1[j]] + ...`. Then define `bar` and `adding` once, outside the loop, and update them in-place: `@. bar = max(0, array1 - 0.2)` and `array2 .+= bar` and `@. array1 = array1 - bar + adding`. You may also want `@inbounds adding[i, j] = ...`, after which this is 10x faster than the original, for me.

Comment: You can also write things like `bar[i, mod1(j+1, n)]` to avoid `foo1` etc. It's simpler, appears to be a little faster. Since `mod` isn't free, you might look into making all the arrays slightly larger than required so that you can safely index `bar[i, j+1]` always. Or iterate over the edges (where mod is needed) separately from the loop over most `i in 2:n-1, j in 2:n-1` (where mod is not needed).

Comment: @mcabbott Thank you. I tried taking `sum([bar[i, foo1[j]], ...`  apart to `bar[i, foo1[j]] + ...` and it get faster a little. Using dot notations also worked. `@inbounds` did not speed up the code.

Comment: @mcabbott Defining `foo1` etc is for circulating the iteration. I want `foo1[j]` in `bar[i,foo1[j]]` etc refer to the first element when the iterator go beyond the last element, like a Torus. The first thing I did was to use `ifelse` statement when designating the index of `bar`, but I noticed evaluation of condition inside a loop takes a lot 
 resource of computation, so I decided to make `foo1` and it indeed contributed a bit for fastening the code.

Comment: @mcabbott I didn't know `mod1` function. I would like to try it later. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @ten: if all parts of your arrays wrap around at the same point, break the inner loop up into pieces: loop over one contiguous piece, then do a separate loop over the other piece.  So you never have any conditional stuff inside any of the loops, and you don't need redundant copies of the same data that costs more memory bandwidth / cache footprint.  (And BTW, "fastening" means "fasten two things together", e.g. with glue or screws.  "quickening" or "speeding up" do mean "to make faster".)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, especially using [LoopVectorization.jl](https://github.com/JuliaSIMD/LoopVectorization.jl) -- though there are a few other optimizations we have to do first before we're in the ballpark where this is the limiting factor.

First, some initial timings of your code on my system (an oldish laptop) using [BenchmarkTools.jl](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl)

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @benchmark Test()
BechmarkTools.Trial: 31 samples with 1 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):    5.987 μs … 257.525 ms  ┊ GC (min … max):  0.00% … 22.07%
 Time  (median):     234.396 ms               ┊ GC (median):    16.67%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   162.310 ms ± 114.023 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  18.44% ±  8.84%

  █                                                        ▂     
  █▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▅▅█▅██▁▃ ▁
  5.99 μs          Histogram: frequency by time          258 ms <

 Memory estimate: 9.84 KiB, allocs estimate: 70.
```

There seems to be some pronounced bimodality between cases where the loop short circuits in only a few tens of evaluations vs cases where it runs the full 100000. As an aside, this is a classic example of why despite some conventional wisdom, minimum times are not a great metric for benchmarking, and either means or (even better) full histograms are much better -- so the histograms from [BenchmarkTools.jl](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl) or [BenchmarkHistograms.jl](https://github.com/ericphanson/BenchmarkHistograms.jl) are great.

Let's start with a few general optimizations (reducing unnecessary allocations, etc.)

```
function test()

    n=5
    sqn = n^2
    r = collect(1:n)
    foo1 = circshift(r', (0, 1))
    foo2 = circshift(r', (0, -1))
    foo3 = circshift(r, 1)
    foo4 = circshift(r, -1)


    # initialize array1 with random entries
    array1 = randn(n,n);
    # initialize array2 with zeros
    array2 = zeros(n,n);
    # Initialize temporary arrays used in loops
    bar = zeros(n, n)
    adding = zeros(n, n)

    loop = 0
    while minimum(array1) < -0.8 && loop < 100000
                loop += 1
                fill!(bar, 0)

                # Use simd?
                @inbounds for i = 1:sqn
                    bar[i] = max(0, array1[i] - 0.2)
                end

                @. array2 += bar

                fill!(adding, 0)
                # Use simd?
                @inbounds for i = 1:n
                    for j = 1:n
                        s = bar[i, foo1[j]] + bar[i, foo2[j]] + bar[foo3[i], j] + bar[foo4[i], j]
                        adding[i, j] = 0.25 * s
                    end
                end
                @. array1 = array1 - bar + adding
            end
   return array1, array2, loop
end
```

As you can see, I moved the allocations for `bar` and `adding` outside of the loop -- since they don't change size, we can just allocate them once and then just refill with zeros if necessary. Another change involves unnecessary allocation on assignment when you are adding and subtracting arrays. The original `array1 = array1 - bar + adding` for example is allocating, but `@. array1 = array1 - bar + adding`, which is just a convenient shorthand for `array1 .= array1 .- bar .+ adding`, makes explicit that we want element-wise operations, and will ensure that they all occur in-place (i.e., without triggering new heap allocations). I also put an `@inbounds` on the `for` loops and refactored the summation in the innermost loop a bit (while `sum` is fast, allocating a brand new array for it to add up on each iteration of the loop is *not*, as mentioned in the comments).

This seems to give us about a 10x mean speedup, and substantially reduces our allocations and memory usage.

```
julia> @benchmark test()
BechmarkTools.Trial: 305 samples with 1 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):   1.622 μs … 30.093 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     22.438 ms              ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   16.429 ms ± 11.530 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%

  █                                           ▁                
  █▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁█▇▄▃▃▄▃▅▅▂▃▃▂▃▂ ▂
  1.62 μs         Histogram: frequency by time        29.4 ms <

 Memory estimate: 1.75 KiB, allocs estimate: 9.
```

Now for the SIMD. It turns out that just adding `@inbounds @simd` in front of the for loops doesn't appear from the timings to enable any optimizations that Julia's compiler isn't already finding. [LoopVectorization](https://github.com/JuliaSIMD/LoopVectorization.jl)'s `@turbo` does, however:

```
using Random, LoopVectorization

function test_simd_turbo()

    n=5
    sqn = n^2
    r = collect(1:n)
    foo1 = circshift(r', (0, 1))
    foo2 = circshift(r', (0, -1))
    foo3 = circshift(r, 1)
    foo4 = circshift(r, -1)


    # initialize array1 with random entries
    array1 = randn(n,n);
    # initialize array2 with zeros
    array2 = zeros(n,n);
    # Initialize temporary arrays used in loops
    bar = zeros(n, n)
    adding = zeros(n, n)

    loop = 0
    while minimum(array1) < -0.8 && loop < 100000
                loop += 1
                fill!(bar, 0)

                # Use simd?
                @turbo for i = 1:sqn
                    bar[i] = max(0, array1[i] - 0.2)
                end

                @turbo @. array2 += bar

                fill!(adding, 0)
                # Use simd?
                @turbo for i = 1:n
                    for j = 1:n
                        s = bar[i, foo1[j]] + bar[i, foo2[j]] + bar[foo3[i], j] + bar[foo4[i], j]
                        adding[i, j] = 0.25 * s
                    end
                end
                @turbo @. array1 = array1 - bar + adding
            end
   return array1, array2, loop
end
```

Note that you can use `@turbo` to SIMD-vectorize both `for` loops and `@.` broadcasts, as seen here.

This gives us about another 1.5x speedup, for a total of nearly 15x over the original implementation

```
julia> @benchmark test_simd_turbo()
BechmarkTools.Trial: 419 samples with 1 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):   1.864 μs … 28.059 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     15.486 ms              ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   11.946 ms ±  8.034 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%

  █                                                            
  █▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▇▇▆▅▄▄▃▄▄▄▃▃▂▁▂▁▁▁▂▁▁▁▁▁▁▃ ▂
  1.86 μs         Histogram: frequency by time        26.3 ms <

 Memory estimate: 1.75 KiB, allocs estimate: 9.
```

The advantage for LoopVectorization.jl would likely be even greater on a system with [AVX512](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512) vector registers (I only have AVX2 on this laptop).